# Cash Component in Index

Tags: stocks, etf, index-fund, cash, market-indexes

In one of the office discussions today, it came up that index, for example, can have cash also. This information was new to me and I couldn't understand why an Index will have cash?

Could someone please explain? Thanks.

Comment: Are you talking about the index, or a mutual fund that is supposed to follow the index?

Comment: Index, such as s&p 500

Answer (score 1):

I presume you're talking about an index *fund* or ETF that *tracks* a specific index. An index itself is usually just an abstract collection of various instruments (e.g. stocks) that are used to represent some market segment. Since they're abstract (and not based on actual holdings) they don't have to deal with daily transactions to rebalance the index.

An index *fund* or *ETF* does not necessarily hold every single component of an actual index (e.g. S&P-500 tracking indices don't necessarily hold all 500 stocks in the index) or in exactly the same proportion as the index. It's goal is to *emulate* the index as close as possible. It may drift slightly depending on how the underlying stocks perform, and can keep cash on hand to allow the managers to buy stocks without having to liquidate existing positions.